# UICollectionView cannot scroll while containing UIScrollView decelerates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I've implemented pretty common pattern: you could scroll horizontally between views (paging enabled) and you could scroll any "page" down for more details. It is done with parent `UICollectionView` containing `UIScrollViews`, see enclosed image:

[image: test]

Collection View can scroll only horizontally, Scroll View can scroll only vertically.
However I am unable to achieve "proper" horizontal scrolling. I cannot scroll horizontally while inner scroll view is **decelerating** which heavily decreases UX quality. Tried so far: directionalLockEnabled, delaysContentTouches, canCancelContentTouches, touchesShouldBegin: and gestures with requireGestureRecognizerToFail - all without success (but maybe not all done right).

Comment: That's because paging is enabled. It will cause that kind of pause effect to move from page to page. It's the default behaviour

Comment: I guess that the while the child `scrollView`s are decelerating, they swallow touches (to be able to tap to stop deceleration or to scroll the child again). I'm not sure if any combination of properties will fix this. As a laster resort, you can override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method on the child `scrollView`s in order to send those touches both to the current child `scrollView` and to the parent `collectionView`.